# Spring Boot. @DataJpaTest H2 embedded database create schema

Tags: spring-boot, integration-testing, h2, spring-test, embedded-database

I have couple of entities in my data layer stored in particular schema. For example:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "FOO", schema = "DUMMY")
public class Foo {}
```

I'm trying to setup H2 embedded database for integration testing of my data layer.
I'm using `@DataJpaTest` annotation for my tests to get H2 embedded database configured automatically. However, the creation of tables fails because schema `DUMMY` is not created at DB initialization.

Any ideas on how to create schema before creation of tables in test cases?

I've tried to use @Sql(statements="CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS DUMMY") but didn't succeed.

Also, I've tried to set `spring.datasource.url = jdbc:h2:mem:test;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS DUMMY` in my `test.properties` file together with `TestPropertySource("classpath:test.properties")`, but that didn't work too.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I had the same issue, I managed to resolve by creating schema.sql (in resources folder) with the content

`CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS <yourschema>`

Documentation can be found [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html#howto-initialize-a-database-using-hibernate) but imho the lack of real examples make it very complex.
Warning: this script is also executed within the normal (not test) environment.

Not mandatory, but good practice, add h2 dependency only in test scope

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
   <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
   <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: thanks for reply. It works! BTW, nice catch about scope of dependency.

Comment: Also, I've found another solution for this problem, just 've forgotten to place it here.

Comment: it turned out that you can put `schema.sql` under `src/test/resources` to apply it only for tests

Answer (score 6):

I think you are looking for this annotation:

> @AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace=Replace.NONE)

example:

```
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace= AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
class UserRepoTest {...}
```

Comment: I would expect this to delete/drop you productive Database instead of using H2.

Answer (score 3):

After couple hours of struggling I've found a workaround.

You can define `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema = DUMMY` in your `application.properties`.

And then set `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema =` in your `test.properties` and use together with `@TestPropertySource("classpath:test.properties")`

So, in this way the schema DUMMY won't be created and the entities will be created in default schema.

Comment: You can also use `@TestPropertySource(properties = "spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=...")`

Answer (score 2):

In my case `schema.sql` under `test/resources` din't worked.

The following configuration in `test/resources/application.yml` file worked.

```
spring:
  datasource:
    username: sa
    password: sa
    driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:usrmgmt;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;MODE=MYSQL;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS DUMMY;
  liquibase:
    change-log: classpath:db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml
```

In the above configuration, provided the below additional configuration

1. `INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS DUMMY` extension to the existing DB url. In the absence of this, faced the exception `Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Schema "DUMMY" not found;`.
2. `spring.liquibase.change-log` property. In the absence of this, faced the exception `Caused by: liquibase.exception.ChangeLogParseException: classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml does not exist`.